# Delete Last and First Char in a String

Tags: java

I just wanted to ask how to remove the first and the last char form a String. The easiest and best looking would be great :)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
String s = "Hello World!";
s = s.substring(1, s.length() - 1); // --> "ello World"
```

Answer (score 5):

Use the substring() method:

```
String newString = oldString.substring(1, oldString.length() -1);
```

This skips the first char and substrings down to the end minus 1.

Answer (score 3):

You can take advatage of [String.substring()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29) method:

```
public String removeFirstAndLastChar(String s)
{
   String withoutFirstChar = s.substring(1);

   return withoutFirstChar.substring(withoutFirstChar.length() - 1);
}
```

or shorter way:

```
public String removeFirstAndLastChar(String s)
{
   return s.substring(1, s.length() - 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use [`String.substring()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/manipstrings.html).

Answer (score 0):

Read about text functions:

```
substring(int start, int end);
length();
```

Here http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html